# How to use needsInputModeSwitchKey properly?

Tags: swift, ios-keyboard-extension

When i try to use (anywhere and anytime in my code) `needsInputModeSwitchKey` property from `UIInputViewController` i'm facing with warning:

> -[UIInputViewController needsInputModeSwitchKey] was called before a connection was established to the host application. This will produce an inaccurate result. Please make sure to call this after your primary view controller has been initialized.

Despite the warning, i get correct value and it looks weird. What should i do to remove this warning?

Comment: getting same warning. Did you found solution?

Comment: I'm also confused by this as it's what is added by default when the extension is added. I guess right now any calls that would be before the value is reliable are simply replaced and eventually isHidden reaches the right value, but, I'm not sure whether they intended this to be changed for the example or what the intention was. Did you end up doing anything different from the example or simply left as-is?

Comment: Hi Luke. No, unfortunately I left it as it is.